# wordpress instillation error read only mode

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to install word press local on xampp and it works fine and the Apache and MySQL work fine on it , i create also new database using PHP myadmin and add new user with user name and password and i download word press file and  put inside htdocs inside Xampp folders but when i try to install word press its give me this strange error

> (
>   WordPress database error: [InnoDB is in read only mode.] CREATE TABLE
>   wp_users ( ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, user_login
>   varchar(60) NOT NULL default '', user_pass varchar(64) NOT NULL
>   default '', user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '', user_email
>   varchar(100) NOT NULL default '', user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL
>   default '', user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00', user_activation_key varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
>   user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0', display_name varchar(250)
>   NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (ID), KEY user_login_key
>   (user_login), KEY user_nicename (user_nicename) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER
>   SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

i tried to create even a new database, change password and make sure password right and all this but still same issue can I change the database to not read only from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the read only mode from PhpMyAdmin section, when you open Php My admin you will see the tabs database  SQL  Status  User
Go to Users and select your user and then you can change the user privileges by editing user privileges select all privileges and save then you can have all access and read only mode will be changed.

Comment: when i try to create table inside the database give me error #1874-innoDB is in read only mode